# The requestBody doesn't show up in the call

Tags: javascript, swagger, openapi

When I define a requestBody, it doesn't show up in the swagger docs. I want to create an array of images and a single file upload for a gpx file in the swagger. How can I achieve that the requestBody shows just like the parameters property?

So far I've tried to declare it like the code below. I haven't tried to make a requestBodies component out of it and calling that reference, but I don't think that's the problem.

```
/**
 * @openapi
 * /routes:
 *   post:
 *     description: Create a route
 *     tags:
 *       - Routes
 *     security:
 *       - CustomToken: []
 *     requestBody:
 *       content:
 *         multipart/form-data:
 *           schema:
 *             type: object
 *             required:
 *               - images
 *               - track
 *             properties:
 *               images:
 *                 type: array
 *                 minItems: 1
 *                 maxItems: 3
 *                 items:
 *                   type: string
 *                   format: binary
 *               track:
 *                 type: string
 *                 format: binary
 *             encoding:
 *               images:
 *                 contentType: image/png, image/jpeg
 *     parameters:          
 *       - name: name
 *         description: Name of the route.
 *         in: query
 *         required: true
 *         type: string
 *         example: Utrecht naar Den Bosch
 *       - name: description
 *         description: Description of the route.
 *         in: query
 *         required: true
 *         type: string
 *         example: Een route die langs de prachtigste punten gaat op de route van utrecht naar Den Bosch.
 *       - name: price
 *         description: The price of the route using the purchasable coins as the currency.
 *         in: query
 *         required: true
 *         type: integer
 *         minimum: 0
 *         example: 1
 *       - name: rating
 *         description: The rating the route has been given.
 *         in: query
 *         required: false
 *         type: integer
 *         minimum: 1
 *         maximum: 5
 *         example: 5
 *       - name: tags
 *         description: The tags that define if the route contains dikes, forests, mountains or cities. To select multiple values hold ctrl and click on the values you want.
 *         in: query
 *         required: true
 *         type: array
 *         minItems: 1
 *         maxItems: 4
 *         uniqueItems: true
 *         items:
 *           type: string
 *           enum:
 *             - Dike
 *             - Forest
 *             - Mountain
 *             - City
 *         example:
 *           - Dike
 *           - Forest
 *     responses:
 *       200:
 *         description: succesfully created a route
 */
```

According to the examples I've found, this is how you declare a requestBody. But the values don't show up in the swagger docs file as seen here: [image: Swagger docs page]

Comment: Do you use OpenAPI 2.0 (indicated by `swagger: "2.0"` in the generated API definition file) or OpenAPI 3.0 (`openapi: 3.0.0`)? Your annotations use a mix of 2.0 and 3.0 syntax, which is probably why it doesn't work.

Comment: @Helen I use OpenAPI 3.0, if I look up the json file that's generated it shows the following: `{"info":{"title":"<main-service-gateway>","version":"1.0.0"},"openapi":"3.0.0","servers":[]`

Comment: @Helen also what are the parts that are written in OpenAPI 2.0? Because I did go from 2.0 to 3.0 recently and still need to change a few things to get it to the syntax of 3.0. I thought I had changed everything, so would love to know what I forgot to change. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What library/framework do you use to generate the OpenAPI file from these annotations? Also, what is your Swagger UI version? (Open the browser dev tools > Console and evaluate `versions`.)

Comment: The library I use is openapi-jsdoc https://www.npmjs.com/package/openapi-jsdoc.  The swagger-ui version is  "3.0.12/g2567e51-dirty".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3.0.12 is a very old version of Swagger UI and does not support OpenAPI 3.0 (OAS3 support was added in Swagger UI [v. 3.1](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/releases/tag/v3.1.0)). You need to update your Swagger UI. The latest version (3.22 at the time of writing) displays OpenAPI 3.0 request bodies properly.

There are also a few issues with the annotations:

- In the request body, `encoding` must be on the same level as `schema` and not inside `schema`.
- Parameter type definitions must be wrapped into `schema`, like so:

  ```
  *       - name: price
  *         description: The price of the route using the purchasable coins as the currency.
  *         in: query
  *         required: true
  *         schema:          # <------
  *           type: integer
  *           minimum: 0
  *         example: 1

  ...

  *       - name: tags
  *         description: The tags that define if the route contains dikes, forests, mountains or cities. To select multiple values hold ctrl and click on the values you want.
  *         in: query
  *         required: true
  *         schema:          # <------
  *           type: array
  *           minItems: 1
  *           maxItems: 4
  *           uniqueItems: true
  *           items:
  *             type: string
  *             enum:
  *               - Dike
  *               - Forest
  *               - Mountain
  *               - City
  *         example:
  *           - Dike
  *           - Forest
  ```

Comment: Do you perhaps know how I can update de swagger-ui version? I have folder in my api that contains all the swagger-ui components like: swagger-ui-bundle.js, swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js, swagger-ui.css and swagger-ui.js

Comment: If you have `swagger-ui` as a dependency in `package.json`, update the version there. If you added those files manually, download the [Swagger UI repository](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui) and take the corresponding files from the `dist` folder.